# pycharm 2019: how to change size of file font in project view?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

The font size of files in my project view feels cramped, and the font size of file name in my tab seems very small.

How do I change their sizes?

[image]

I tried `Appearance -> use custom font` but tweaking the values didn't work -- it resulted in the font being either too big or too similar.

Answer (score 0):

To enable changing font size in the editor #
In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), click General under Editor. The General page opens.

Make sure that the setting Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+MouseWheel is enabled.

To change font size using the mouse wheel #
Place the caret in the editor.

While keeping the Ctrl/ ⌘ key pressed, rotate the mouse wheel. As you rotate the mouse wheel forward, font size grows larger; as you rotate the mouse wheel backwards, font size decreases.
The macOS users can use the trackpad "Pinch-to-Zoom" gesture to change the size of the font and the whole editing area.

Comment: but this solution doesn't work if you want to change font size of filenames in tab/project structure. :(